# Can I auto-generate my get/set methods in c#?

Tags: c#

Takes -ages- by hand. Can I not just select my properties and click a button?

They look like this:

```
private bool _Monday = false;
private bool _Tuesday = false;
private bool _Wednesday = false;
private bool _Thursday = false;
private bool _Friday = false;
private bool _Saturday = false;
private bool _Sunday = false;
```

and there are LOADS of them.

Comment: @Outlaw:  how so?  All of those fields are private.

Comment: @SLC - If they are private, why do you want them as properties?

Comment: Cos I am using legacy code :(

Comment: @outlaw : what is the problem of having private fields?? as far as i know it is a good practice and also is recommended by OOP

Comment: @dave private properties can't be accessed outside of the class (as I'm sure you know). As such, there's not much use in having a get/set method for something you can access directly.

Comment: @FuriousFolder it is not that simple. although your comment refers to a design theory described in an article named : "getter/setter's are evil".

Comment: @FuriousFolder i guess your point of view is different from the author of mentioned article. i use getter/setter's to eliminate the dependency and propose a controlled way to access properties.(the article claims that using accessor methods also creates unwanted dependency that is hard to manage so any change in properties will have butterfly effect in app)

Comment: @dave I've not read that particular article :p Yes, using accessor methods does created dependencies. In C# though, declaring a getter/setter is as simple as: `public bool myProp {get;set;}` (if you weren't aware)
As such, it's pretty clean, and "getting" the property doesn't require a method call, at least, not in the conventional sense. The syntax would read `myObj.myProp = true` In C# however, the scope of the set "method" is at least as restrictive as the property's scope. So if you have a private property, you can't set it outside the class anyway

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The current version of C# (3.0) has auto properties:

```
public bool Monday { get; set; }
// etc …
```

(You don’t need your fields now, backing fields are generated by the compiler.)
Unfortunately, they do not support (*yet*) initialization expressions – but in your example you don’t need them since `false` is the default value for `bool`s anyway.

Comment: @John: please only edit if you add value … I omitted `private` on purpose. We don’t know if the OP wants that here.

Answer (score 14):

You can **right-click** on the field and go to **Refactor > Encapsulate Field**. That will generate a Property. You still have to do each one at a time but it's a lot faster than the typing!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [automatic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) with C# 3.0 or later:

```
public bool Monday { get; set; }
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
private bool _Monday;
public bool Monday
{
    get { return _Monday; }
    set { _Monday = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl+K, Ctrl+X  opens up code snippets.  Type 'prop' for a property declaration code snippet.  You can tab through the snippet fields and fill them in.  Hit enter to complete the snippet.

Comment: You can do one better here.  Just type "prop\t\t" to shortcut the opening of the code snippets menu

Answer (score 1):

if you use visual studio just type prop then press tab and visual studio will let you chose the type and name of the property

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins to Visual Studio have functionality for creation of properties based on private fields ([ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is a good example).

Answer (score 0):

We use [code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k%28VS.80%29.aspx) that allow us to provide the datatype and property name on the fly. We also have the option of providing a OnPropertyChanged event.